# Create a new variable with a function

Tags: c++, variables

I am trying to figure out if i can make a 'myclass' class variable with a function that has a string parameter. The variable should be the string input.

The function i would like to create would look something like this:

```
void makevariable(string name){
    myclass name;
    }
```

The problem is that this function wouldn't work. The desired effect would be if string name = 'apple', a myclass variable apple would be created. Note that i am using C++.

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do this? Ie: give a particular use case?

Comment: That's not really possible in C++. There are ways you can [*map*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) a string with an object, but maybe that's not what you want? Perhaps if you explain *why* you want to do this we might be able to help you better? What is the *real* problem you want to solve like this? Please take some time to [read about the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and think about how this question might be one.

Comment: Even if it were possible how would you use created variable outside of the function?

Comment: Well during an exam i had to write an mp3 player able to make playlists. We were allowed to assume that all input names would be unique. So i thought there should be a way to create a playlist variable called that input name. (Later i realised i could just use playlist.name to store the name of the playlist, so i'm not looking for a solve on how to do it, but i want to know if my initial thought would have been possible as I've been thinking about it a lot lately)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, once code is compiled all the names are gone.  It would be a useless exercise anyway.  You could have a String member variable in your class (maybe called name) and set it equal to your String when you create your class.

You should also be aware that your statement as written would create an object that would immediately go out of scope as soon as makevariable function exits.  Generally you would just use the class constructor as the function you're after.

Assuming the constructor takes a string and puts it in the name field.

```
    void someFunction(){

         String someString = "apple";
         String someOtherString = "banana";

         MyClass anInstance = MyClass(someString);
         MyClass anotherInstance = MyClass(someOtherString);

         //  More code using these instances
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to do that in C++, it's static programming language. And if it were possible, how would you use this variable outside of the function? It's local.

But, instead you can the following:

```
class myclass {};
unordered_map<string, myclass> myclasses;

void makevariable(string name) {
    myclasses[name];
}

int main()
{
    string name = "var1";
    makevariable(name);
    myclasses[name];
    myclasses.erase(name);
}
```